# NaN with py form excel to csv

Tags: python, excel, pandas, txt

I'd like to export 1 column from excel to txt. I tried this:

---

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_excel('C:/Events.xlsx', sheet_name='Data') 

xlsx = pd.read_excel('C:/Events.xlsx', sheet_name='Data') 

xlsx = pd.read_excel('C:/Events.xlsx','Data', usecols='F:F')

with open('C:/filename.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    xlsx.to_string(outfile, index=False)
```

---

output:

```
 20220,333333333333333
NaN
```

The problem are:
-I found first blank space.
-in second row I found NaN.

Do you have any ideas?

Thank you for your support
Angelo

Comment: Do you have a sample of your excel file to show? What is expected? It is hard to understand the problem without context.

Comment: Hi Mattheus, here you find test file .xlsx: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k-QndKkWlIPZmRp5kdOuyB_j228PDwRL/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=116140305213235536440&rtpof=true&sd=true      Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the test file it looks like the cell in the second row (in col F) is blank. Pandas will automatically read in blank cells as NaN. Is this row blank in the main file too?

If you have blank cells and you don't want to read them in as datatype NaN, you can convert them to empty string instead by using the `keep_default_na` parameter when importing the file:

```
    pd.read_excel('your_file_name.csv', keep_default_na=False)
```

Does this help?

Comment: Amazing, glad I could help! :) Would you mind accepting the answer in this case? Thanks

Comment: Yes I accept your answer. It works

Comment: Hi, thanks :) You just need to click the 'tick' next to the question to accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

In the test file it looks like the cell in the second row (in col F) is blank. Pandas will automatically read in blank cells as NaN. Is this row blank in the main file too?

If you have blank cells and you don't want to read them in as datatype NaN, you can convert them to empty string instead by using the keep_default_na parameter when importing the file:

```
pd.read_excel('your_file_name.csv', keep_default_na=False)
```

graceface

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).